# Построение круговой диаграммы Java

Tags: java

Пытаюсь построить круговую диаграмму на основе массива, которая будет отражать элемент, и в зависимости сколько раз она повторяется какая-то часть диаграммы ему будет соответствовать. Сделал все по классике: создал map, в него записываю элемент массива и количество повторений. Столкнулся с проблемой вывода (см. рисунок). Проблема состоит в том что в массиве 1 встречается чаще, но на диаграмме ей соответствует меньшая область, чем например 5, которая встречается всего 1 раз;

```
public class CreateChart extends JFrame{

    public CreateChart(String appTitle, String chartTitle)
    {
        PieDataset dataset = createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset,chartTitle);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500,300));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }


    private PieDataset createDataset()
    { int[] mas = {1,1,1,2,2,4,3,2,3,4,5};
      Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

     for(int i=0;i<mas.length;++i)
     {
         if(map.containsKey(mas[i]))
         {
             map.put(mas[i], map.get(mas[i])+1);
         }
         else {map.put(mas[i], 1);}
     }

      DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();

      for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) 
      {
          result.setValue(entry.getKey().toString(),(int)entry.getValue()); 
      }
    }
    private JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset, String title)
    {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(title, dataset, true, true, false);

        PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setStartAngle(90);
        plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
        plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            CreateChart CC = new CreateChart("Pie Chart Test","OS Comparison");
            CC.pack();
            CC.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            CC.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Забыл добавить рисунок. 1 встречается чаще но на диаграмме для нее область меньше

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление**

Заметил ошибку в методе rezult.setValue(). Правильно будет

```
for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) 
      {
          result.setValue(entry.getValue().toString(),(int)entry.getKey());
      }
```

Но теперь диаграмма отображает не все элементы (нет 4 и 5).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код из первой части у меня работает правильно, если все-таки вернуть результат в `createDataset()`. Иначе код не компилируется. То, что вы написали в обновлении - неверно, т.к. у вас в значениях - число повторов, а в ключах - значения элемента массива, частоту которых вы считаете. Поскольку элементы в массиве повторяются 1, 2 или 3 раза, вы получаете 3 сектора на диаграме, а значением сектора является последний добавленный в датасет ключ.

Comment: Крч, прозреваю, что на момент создания первого скриншота в коде было что-то типа `result.setValue(entry.getKey().toString(),(int)entry.getKey());`, а сейчас это все можно закрывать, как опечатку.

Answer (score 1):

Проверил все работает. `result.setValue` принимает в качестве второго аргумента тип `double`, поэтому разумнее пользоваться приведением типа к `double`(если версия Java 7 или выше) или `Double`.

```
for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
     result.setValue(entry.getKey().toString(), (Double)entry.getValue());
}
```

[image: Скрин]